# iframe src not changing on button click in Django

Tags: django, html, iframe

In my web page Im using published map from Geoexplorer in iframe src.On button click I want to load another service in same iframe but its not working.
my html code in map.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<nav>
 <button type="button" onclick="go()">Actual plant functional type</button> 
</nav>

<section>
<iframe  id="test" style="border: none;" height="494" width="1100"  src="http://localhost:8080/geoexplorer/viewer/#maps/1"></iframe>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
function go() {
    document.getElementById("test").src = "http://localhost:8080/geoexplorer/viewer/#maps/2";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't find a problem with your code.

Comment: Yes. Im not able to figure out the problem.

Comment: What happens when you run? Have you double checked the path to the 2nd map exists? Have you used a `console.log` to check the `go()` function is firing?

Comment: Yes go() function is firing when I include other url. I even cross checked the 2nd map. It works when I load it in browser. I'm stuck with this:(

Comment: What are the contents of the urls? I'm thinking that the 2nd map might be too large? I have tested your code locally with dummy images and it works perfectly.

Comment: And what browser (and version) are you using?

Comment: 2nd map contains just few point data. I'm using chrome version 47.0.2526.106 m

Comment: try to do document.getElementById("test")[0].src = "http://localhost:8080/geoexplorer/viewer/#maps/2";